# SFTP connection to Windows Azure virtual machine permissions issue

Tags: ubuntu, permissions, azure

I've set up an Ubuntu 12.04 VM on the Windows Azure cloud. I can connect to it using WinSCP, but I can only alter files in the user directory (/home/myuser). Which really beats the prupose because I wanted to use this instance a webserver.
What should I do to enable such interaction with the VM?